# Unable to connect with wpa_supplicant

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, wpa-supplicant

I try to connect with wifi (WPA2) using wpa_supplicant

```
root@bamt-miner:~# iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: AC:F1:DF:24:93:D6
                    Protocol:802.11b/g/n
                    ESSID:"MYWIFI"
                    Mode:Managed
                    Channel:1
                    Quality:52/100  Signal level:-69 dBm  Noise level:-95 dBm
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:150 Mb/s
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

root@bamt-miner:~# wpa_supplicant -Dwext  -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
ioctl[SIOCGIWSCAN]: Resource temporarily unavailable
Associated with ac:f1:df:24:93:d6
CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
Trying to associate with ac:f1:df:24:93:d6 (SSID='MYWIFI' freq=2412 MHz)
Associated with ac:f1:df:24:93:d6
CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
Authentication with 00:00:00:00:00:00 timed out.
Trying to associate with ac:f1:df:24:93:d6 (SSID='MYWIFI' freq=2412 MHz)
Associated with ac:f1:df:24:93:d6
CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
^CCTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING - signal 2 received
root@bamt-miner:~#

root@bamt-miner:~# iwlist scan
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down
```

/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf content

```
network={
        ssid="MYWIFI"
        #psk="paleta2001fido"
        psk=3e0389388ee7dbe34f81753b0fb4ff2a5efa1fbc922b346c920ed396a772c9ed
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: note your password is visible in plain text

Answer (score 0):

You are associating then getting disconnected before completion of the 4 way handshake (I don't see the 802.11 authentication step but presumably this is happening as you can't associate without it). 
I'd hazard a guess that this is caused by one of the following:

1) Your PSK is incorrect (most likely).
2) You have been blacklisted by the AP for some reason (try restarting the AP, or waiting a while).
3) A bug on the AP. Its not clear if the DISCONNECT event is because you are being disassociated/deauthed by the AP, or if the supplicant itself is tearing down the connection. The supplicant may do it if it doesn't receive M1 of the handshake within a timeout, which in turn could be because the AP is in a strange state. Again, reset it to clear.

A wireshark capture, ideally an airtrace taken from a seperate wifi card in monitor mode, or at worst a capture taken on the bamt-miner machine itself, capturing its wifi interface would help give more idea of what is happening. You may also get some useful driver log in dmesg.
Hope that helps!